# Pandas dataframes sorting/partitioning within multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe like such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'class': ['Opn', 'Opn', 'MA', 'CoNo', 'Opn'],
    'title': ['Title1', 'Title1', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title2'],
    'event_count': [16, 11, 8, 7, 5]
})
```

How can I sort values descending within class and then within title so the output would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify your sorting conditions. What does "then within title" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a tmp column similar to what Andrej suggested, but the sum was on the event_count column.

```
df2 = df.groupby(['class', 'title']).sum()
df3['total_count'] = df2.groupby('class')['event_count'].transform('sum')
df3 = df3.sort_values(by=['class', 'event_count'], ascending=[False, False]).reset_index()
df4 = df3.drop(columns=['total_count'])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can do:

```py
df = df.groupby(["class", "title"], as_index=False).sum()
df["tmp"] = df["title"].str.extract(r"Title(.*)").astype(int)
df = df.sort_values(by=["class", "tmp"], ascending=[False, True]).drop(columns="tmp")

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  class   title  event_count
2   Opn  Title1           27
3   Opn  Title2            5
1    MA  Title2            8
0  CoNo  Title3            7
```

Comment: Why is `df["tmp"]` required? Couldn't you just use `by=["class", "title"]` and get the same result?

Comment: @user19077881 If there's  `Title10` and more, simple string comparison won't work.

Comment: I think this code only works because `Title1` has a higher `event_count` than `Title2`. If you try changing `df.loc[1] = ['Opn', 'Title2', 12]` the results are not sorted properly.